# In Python, How do I skip to a specific line in a script?

Tags: python, raw-input

I am making a script that opens programs, in this case, Google Chrome and iTunes. Google Chrome comes first, and in the script it asks if you want to enter the password to launch Google Chrome. If the user types 'Yes' then it asks for the password, etc.
However, iTunes is several lines lower in the script, So is there any way that I can make the program go to the iTunes part of the script if the user does not want to launch Chrome?
This is what I have so far, I know there are a lot of errors, But I will get around to fixing those.

```
Chrome = raw_input ('Would You Like to Launch Google Chrome' )
if Chrome == 'Yes' or Chrome == 'yes':

pw = 'memebase145'
password = raw_input('Enter Password to Launch Google Chrome: ')

if password == pw:

import os


os.chdir(r'C:\users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application')
os.startfile ('chrome.exe')
print 'Opening Google Chrome!'
else:
print 'Incorrect Password! Try Again!'
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
password = raw_input ('password: ')
if Chrome == 'No' or Chrome == 'no':
iTunes = raw_input ('Would you like to open iTunes? ')

if iTunes == 'no' or iTunes == 'No':
raise SystemExit 

else:
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
if word == 'ohtygd':
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes')
os.startfile ('iTunes.exe')
print 'Launching iTunes!'
else:
print 'Incorrect Password! Try Again!'
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
```

Comment: Your program has serious formatting and logic issue which makes little sense. Why did you repeat the password line multiple times?

Comment: @Abhijit I couldn't figure out how to make the script ask for a password infinitely if it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the code correct, whether on not Chrome is launched the script will then ask if you want to launch iTunes.

Here is some minimal code to hopefully get you going:

```
import os

chrome = raw_input ('Would You Like to Launch Google Chrome' )
if chrome.lower() == 'yes':

    pw = 'memebase145'
    password = raw_input('Enter Password to Launch Google Chrome: ')

    while password != pw:
        print 'Incorrect Password! Try Again!'
        password = raw_input ('password: ')

    os.chdir(r'C:\users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application')
    os.startfile ('chrome.exe')
    print 'Opening Google Chrome!'

itunes = raw_input ('Would you like to open iTunes? ')
if itunes.lower() == 'yes':
    word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')
    while word != 'ohtygd':
        print 'Incorrect Password! Try Again!'
        word = raw_input ('Second Password for iTunes: ')

    os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes')
    os.startfile ('iTunes.exe')
    print 'Launching iTunes!'
```

Note that the way it is now, if you try to launch Chrome or iTunes you'll be stuck in a loop until you enter the correct password.  I'll leave that for you to fix.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the lines relevant to two different functions, the call the appropriate function according to the input. For example:

```
def Chrome():
    ...
def iTunes():
    ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        i = raw_input("What would you like to launch?")
        if i.lower() == "chrome":
            Chrome()
        elif i.lower() == "itunes":
             iTunes()
        else:
             print "Unrecognized answer.
```

The password detection can be written inside the functions, or if you want a master password, just add a password check first.